# $\Bbb R,\Bbb C,\Bbb H$ are the only complete normed division rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, noncommutative-algebra, complete-spaces

Does anyone have a proof or reference for this often-quoted fact? How complicated is the proof?

> If $K$ is a complete normed division ring, then $K$ is isomorphic to the real numbers, complex numbers, or the quaternions.

Comment: See the [Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(real_division_algebras))

Comment: @Omnomnomnom You should first exclude infinite dimensional division algebras over the reals. See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/45653/infinite-dimensional-normed-division-algebras

Comment: @egreg It seems like the linked result actually shows that it is *not* necessary to exclude infinite-dimensional division algebras, because they don't exist.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Infinite dimensional *normed* division algebras.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom That result seems really close to my statement, but I said division ring, not division algebra over $\Bbb R$. Is that a mis-quoting on my part?

Comment: I think your statement is actually a bit stronger.  In particular, in the Frobenius theorem, we assume that whatever ring you want to build, you should be able to multiply by elements in $\Bbb R$.  I've heard of the Frobenius theorem, but I haven't run into your statement anywhere.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom That's not actually unreasonable. Since it's an additive group, we can multiply by $n\in\Bbb Z$; since it is a ring, we actually have an embedding of $\Bbb Z$ in the ring; since it is a division ring we can divide these elements to embed $\Bbb Q$, and since it is complete, we can use convergent sequences to embed $\Bbb R$ in the ring, and left-multiply by these elements to turn it into an algebra. The only problem is ensuring that the elements converge properly, so that the completion of $\Bbb Q$ gives $\Bbb R$ and not $\Bbb C_p$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I'm now inclined to think that I've mis-stated the theorem, and it should be talking about associative normed division $\Bbb R$-algebras, not complete division rings (and then we are back to Frobenius). I would accept an answer that mentions Frobenius and points out that the statement is false for $\Bbb Q_p$ and  $\Bbb C_p$.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro thanks for that.  However, the observations were yours, so perhaps you should write up that answer yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is false; the fields $\Bbb Q_p$ and $\Bbb C_p$ of [$p$-adic rationals and complexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number) are (metrically) complete normed fields, which are of course not isomorphic to $\Bbb R,\Bbb C,\Bbb H$.

The correct statement along these lines is known as the [Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_%28real_division_algebras%29):

> **Theorem ([Frobenius 1877](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_%28real_division_algebras%29)):** Every finite-dimensional (associative) division algebra over $\Bbb R$ is isomorphic to one of $\Bbb R,\Bbb C,\Bbb H$.

If one drops the requirement of associativity (and adds an inner product), there is a similar statement which reduces the field to these three, plus the set $\Bbb O$ of [octonions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octonion), proven by [Hurwitz in 1898](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz's_theorem_%28composition_algebras%29).

In fact, the assumption that the algebras are finite-dimensional is also unnecessary:

> **Theorem ([Urbanik and Wright 1960](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1960-011-06/S0002-9939-1960-0120264-6/S0002-9939-1960-0120264-6.pdf)):** Every (not necessarily associative) normed division algebra over $\Bbb R$ is isomorphic to one of $\Bbb R,\Bbb C,\Bbb H,\Bbb O$.

Comment: The Frobenius Theorem doesn't make any mention of norms. I thought that "normed" and "finite dimensional" were simply two different conditions that were sufficient to make the theorem, but perhaps every proof of Frobenius Theorem depends on manufacturing a norm out of a finite dimensional algebra, somehow. Certainly we all know the norms that exist on those three algebras.

Comment: @rschwieb Oops, you're right, the norm is a consequence of the Frobenius theorem and not a hypothesis. It seems that the other two theorems do need the assumption to be a hypothesis, though. This makes me curious what kinds of nonassociative non-normed finite-dimensional division algebras exist, since neither Frobenius nor Hurwitz applies in that case.

Comment: It all depends on what you mean by a *norm*; if it is in the usual sense (like Banach spaces, just for clarity), $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is not vector space over the reals, so it can't have a vector space norm.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro The type of norm involved here is [this flavor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_algebra), not norms like those for Banach algebras.

Comment: @egreg I've seen this issue before; I sometimes use the term "norm" in a possibly-not-quite-standard way for [ring absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value_%28algebra%29), which is more appropriate in settings where you don't have that $\Bbb R$-algebra structure but only have a (division) ring. @${}$rschwieb, I assume that comment was directed at @${}$egreg.